# Unable to match full name with spaces in Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Here is the schema.xml

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name"type="StrField"/>
```

Here is the URL I am using to search

```
/solr/mycore/select?q=name:John Smith&fl=\*&wt=json&indent=true
```

Here's the error:

```
Status 400
msg:no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param
```

However, I am able to use "name:John*" to get all the names starting with John. I understand this has something to do with tokenization but not sure what I need to change. The space between the first name and last name is causing some issue with exact match.

The `StrField` is a specific implementation of the "string" so that is not where the issue is as per my undestanding

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: with the error message it seems you didn't specify the fields name in your query. Solr doesn't know what/which field to search by default, since there's no df parameter supplied either. Check if you have field defined in your scheam.xml or define the df param

Comment: check your solrConfig.xml where you will have <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler"> check for <str name="df">name</str>

Comment: If your field a string field, you probably want to search for `name:"John Smith"` so that the whole search string is kept intact. When you don't prefix a value in your query string (or make it a phrase), the default search field is used (the `df` parameter Abhijit mentions).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have included a space character ( ) in the URL.

You need to encode it for HTTP API access with `%20` so it should look like:

```
/solr/mycore/select?q=name:John%20Smith&fl=\*&wt=json&indent=true
```

If you're new to Apache Solr, I recommend you try performing searches using the Solr Admin UI to familiarise yourself with how it works. Cheers!

Comment: Tried that. Still not working

Comment: Sir, I was able to make it work after I put it in double quotes like name:"John Smith"